# How do i post the contents of a row from a table which is a response of a GET request from server?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a javascript code which sends get request to service and puts the xml response in the table,I have created  buttons for each row in the for loop but how do i post the contents of this table's row back to the server?

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "URL OF SERVER", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var option;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>TYPE</th><th>MAKE</th><th>PRICE</th><th>MODEL</th><th>ID</th><th>Select</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("itemnumber");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>"+
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("make")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>"+
x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("model")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>"+
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
 "</td><td>"+  
  "<button>Add item to cart </button>"
    
 "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML = table;

}
```

```html
<html> 
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Smartphones</button>
<table id="dem"></table>
</html>
```

If i call a function in the onclick the same function gets called to all the buttons,so I am kind of stuck here stuck here,any suggestions?
The response for GET request is given in the link below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a unique event handler for each row. But for that, you have to deal with DOM elements instead of generating HTML code and putting it in your table.

I changed your code a bit to be able to use some handmade XML. But you should find what you need in it.

```js
function loadDoc() {
    /* 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "URL OF SERVER", true);
    xhttp.send();
    */
    // manually invoking myFunction because I don't have a xhr 
    myFunction();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var option;
    // var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var xmlDoc = getFakeXml();

    var table = "<tr><th>TYPE</th><th>MAKE</th><th>PRICE</th><th>MODEL</th><th>ID</th><th>Select</th></tr>";
    document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML = table;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("itemnumber");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        // let's create a TR element for each itemnumber 
        var row = createRow(x[i]);
        // appending the created row to your table : 
        document.getElementById("dem").appendChild(row);
    }


}

function createRow(rowData) {
    // local variables : 
    var tr, item = {};
    // create the TR element 
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    // for each field, retrieving data from rowData
    item.type = getField(rowData, "type");
    // and adding a cell to the row : 
    addCell(rowData, item.type, tr);
    item.make = getField(rowData, "make");
    addCell(rowData, item.make, tr);
    item.price = getField(rowData, "price");
    addCell(rowData, item.price, tr);
    item.model = getField(rowData, "model");
    addCell(rowData, item.model, tr);
    item.id = getField(rowData, "id");
    addCell(rowData, item.id, tr);

    // creation of the button element, to be able to add a unique event listener to it :
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Add item to cart";
    button.onclick = function() {
        /* code your event handler here 
        it has access to all the data retrieved from rowData 
        */
        console.log("adding element to cart", item);
    }

    tr.appendChild(button);

    return tr;
}

function getField(rowCell, fieldName) {
    var data = rowCell.getElementsByTagName(fieldName)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    return data;
}

function addCell(rowCell, data, row) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.innerHTML = data;
    row.appendChild(cell);
}

/* this is a just a function returning some fake XML. Only needed for this snippet */
function getFakeXml() {
    var xmlString = `<root><itemnumber>
 <type>Smartphone</type>
 <make>Nokia</make>
 <price>14000.0</price>
 <model>Lumia830</model>
 <id>S00010</id>
</itemnumber>
<itemnumber>
 <type>Smartphone</type>
 <make>Samsung</make>
 <price>10000.0</price>
 <model>Galaxy A5</model>
 <id>S00002</id>
</itemnumber>
<itemnumber>
 <type>Smartphone</type>
 <make>Samsung</make>
 <price>10000.0</price>
 <model>Galaxy A5</model>
 <id>S00001</id>
</itemnumber></root>`;
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    return parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
}
```

```html
<html> 
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Smartphones</button>
<table id="dem"></table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the buttons you create unique by id then add a function to send row back to server.

```
'<button id="button_' + i +'" type="button" onclick="BackToServer(values to pass here)">Add item to cart </button>';
```

Comment: I have created the button inside the javascript so I'm not able to append i,I get syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)? You could save the response data there until you need it again.